# When using typescript and express I can't get res.send to work with explicit types in my controller but it does work when the type is anny

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, model-view-controller

I am trying to set up a project using express and typescript in an MVC configuration, my index.ts does the routing and sends the request and response objects to the appropriate controller function, In my case the home controller GetRoot function.

```
import { request, response } from "express"
import {IHomeController} from "./IHomeController"

export class HomeController implements IHomeController{
    GetRoot(req: Express.Request, res:Express.Response){
        res.send("please let this work");
        return;
    }
}
```

When I use explicit types, as shown above, I get the error "Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Response'."

However, when I use any I am able to use res.send() correctly. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your imports and type declarations to the following

```
import { Request, Response } from "express"
import {IHomeController} from "./IHomeController"

export class HomeController implements IHomeController{
    GetRoot(req: Request, res: Response){
        res.send("please let this work");
        return;
    }
}
```

Or this

```
import * as express from "express"
import {IHomeController} from "./IHomeController"

export class HomeController implements IHomeController{
    GetRoot(req: express.Request, res: express.Response){
        res.send("please let this work");
        return;
    }
}
```